# How can I add a scrollbar to a DIV that contains a table?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML that I am using with browser as new as IE8 and above:

```
<div><table class="grid table">
```

and .css file:

```
.grid {
clear: both;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

This works but when my table is larger than the containing DIV then it goes offscreen.

How can I make it so a scroll bar allows me to scroll my table to the right and left if it is too big for the screen?

Comment: Did you try `overflow: scroll;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `overflow: auto;` CSS declaration to the `div` element.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/AkUp/1/edit)**

**CSS:**

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black; /* Just for demo */

  overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="box">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell #1</td>
            <td>Cell #2</td>
            <td>Cell #3</td>
            <td>Cell #4</td>
            <td>Cell #5</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- so on... -->
    </table>
</div>
```

### Update

If you need only horizontally scroll, use `overflow-x: auto;` instead.

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/AkUp/3/edit)**

Comment: But it's just for horizontal. Not vertical.

Comment: @Alan Then don't mention an height. Mention a width that is not 100%. Like 400px. The `overflow: auto` (or `overflow: scroll` for forcing scrollbars) will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-y:auto;`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/SHbnM/

```
div {
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the overflow attribute to the surrounding div. The documentation is [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/) for that.